# Update information of different user with extension of Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancancan

I setup a platform that uses Devise to create and manage users and CanCanCan to manage permissions. Users have a role (admin or client) that allows them access to certain areas. Admin users have the ability to `can :manage, :all`

I extended Devise so that I have a users/registrations and users/sessions controller.

Admin users have access to views in a ManagerController dashboard that allows them to manage other users. I've figured out how to show the details of a different user, but I can't figure out how to save the information. I get errors that indicate it either can't find the User or that it requires a POST route.

I'm fairly new to Rails, so it could be something simple. I was able to find solutions that included the regular Devise installation, but not the extension. I feel like the problem may be in my routes.

I also can't create new users from here either.

Routes.rb

```
  get 'users' => 'manager#users'
  get 'users/edit' => 'manager#edit'
  post 'users/edit' => 'manager#edit'
  get 'users/new' => 'manager#new'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions: 'users/sessions' }

  devise_scope :user do
      authenticated :user do
        root 'users/registrations#edit', as: :authenticated_root
      end

      unauthenticated do
        root 'users/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
      end
  end
```

Manager Controller

```
class ManagerController < ApplicationController
  authorize_resource :class => false
  include ManagerHelper

  def users
     @users = User.where.not(:id => current_user.id)
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created User." 
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @companies = Company.all

  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    params[:user][:id].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
    params[:user][:id].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:user][:password].blank? and params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?

    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated User."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  end 
  private

  def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :company_id, :role, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

ManagerHelper

```
module ManagerHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

Manager/Edit.html.erb

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>



<%= form_for(resource, :as => @user, :url => edit_user_registration_path(resource_name))  do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :id %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>




    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :company %><br />
      <%= f.collection_select :company_id, @companies, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :role %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :role %>
    </div>



  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <br />
      <em><%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum</em>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I would like the updated information to be saved to the User database.

Currently, I get this error when I click update after changing the user info.

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ManagerController#edit
>   Couldn't find User without an ID
>   Weirdly, when I see the User info, the url is: http://localhost:3000/users/edit?id=2
>   But when I update (and get the error), the url changes to: http://localhost:3000/users/edit.user

I would also like to be able to create New Users from this screen. 
Currently, the user form populates with the information of the user who is logged in. (To be fair, I have been trying to get the edit user correct before tackling this issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many tries later, I've found a solution. There were a lot of errors, so bear with me.

Routes.rb -- Was using the wrong URL in the form submission, so needed to add the routes for the Update function in the Manager controller.

```
  get 'users/edit' => 'manager#edit'
  post 'users/edit' => 'manager#edit'
  get 'users/update' => 'manager#update'
  post 'users/update' => 'manager#update'
```

Manager Controller -- I had to change the password rules so that I could update without a password. Similar concept, slightly different execution.

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:user][:id])
    @companies = Company.all
    if params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
      params[:user].delete(:password)
      params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
    end
    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated User."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Rendered Form.html.erb - Updated with newly created URL path.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: @user, url: users_update_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You want to update existing user info.
If that is the case:
I find your url path is wrong

```
:url => edit_user_registration_path(resource_name)
```

you donot have to user registration here .
If the admin going to update info 
in routes file . some thing like this

```
namespace :admins do
    resources :users
end
```

then use the path creatd from this

Comment: Thank you - I think that brings in a lot more issues than I'd like. When I try to implement it, I have to update a lot of my routes. Unless there's a significant benefit to redo'ing all of it, I'd love a route that just allows me to edit the user.

Comment: Got some IRL help and found the solution. You were correct - it was an issue with my URL, but I couldn't figure out how the route changes you suggested would address it. Thank you for your help. I posted my solution below.